# cups (cups-browsed) doesn't see / recognize USB printer anymore

Tags: server, printing

I have a headless `Ubuntu 20.04` with `cups 2.3.1` and `cups-browsed 1.27.4`. Everything was groovy until I installed an x-server last week to make a package work. This seems to have severly messed with my cups settings because since then there is one (out of three) USB printers that cups doesn't 'see' anymore. I removed the x-server again in the meanwhile and purged both cups and cups-browsed.

`lsusb` can see the printer. The printer in question is the Brother DCP-L5500DN:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 009: ID 04f9:0399 Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-L5500DN series
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 0a5f:0080 Zebra ZTC GK420d
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 04f9:2028 Brother Industries, Ltd QL-570 P-touch Label Printer
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lpstat does already not recognize it as a USB printer:

```
lpstat -v
device for Brother_DCP_L5500DN_series_USB_wiyanna_opti: implicitclass://Brother_DCP_L5500DN_series_USB_wiyanna_opti/
device for Brother_QL-570: usb://Brother/QL-570?serial=D6Z656473
device for Brother_QL_570_Wiyanna_iMac: implicitclass://Brother_QL_570_Wiyanna_iMac/
device for Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_GK420d: usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20GK420d?serial=28J164900175
device for Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_GK420d_Wiyanna_iMac: implicitclass://Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_GK420d_Wiyanna_iMac/
device for Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_GK420d_ZPL: usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20GK420d?serial=28J164900175
device for Zebra_ZPL_wiyanna_opti: implicitclass://Zebra_ZPL_wiyanna_opti/
```

And the web interface for cups-browsed also does not show me the printer as a local printer in the 'Add printers' dialog.

[image]

I have installed the latest Brother DCP-L5500DN drivers from the Brother webpage. Also the printer used to work for years with this setup in the past.  I'm out of ideas. How can I make cups / cups-browsed aware of this particular USB printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it myself. It seems like the kernel module `usblp` was the culprit.

When I ran

```
/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb
```

I got:

```
DEBUG: Failed to detach "usblp" module from 04f9:0399
```

04f9:0399 is the printer in question. So I blacklisted the kernel module and alas, it magically works again!